# memoryError when looping through a huge file, with python 3.8

Tags: python, bigdata, aws-fargate

I need to loop through a huge `csv` file (~120GB), and add 2 new columns.

```py
FILE_NAME = "C:/Temp/large_file.csv"
ENCODING = "utf-8-sig"
IUD_COLUMN_NAME = "stg_stage_load_type"
BATCH_ID_COLUMN_NAME = 'batch_id'

# BUFFER = 20_000_000
BUFFER = 1

print("Opening file")
local_file = open(FILE_NAME, 'rt', encoding=ENCODING, buffering=BUFFER)

hsep = ";"

local_output_file = "C:/Temp/local_test.csv"

iud_val = "I"
batch_id_val = "1607327136305"
print("Open Output file")
with open(local_output_file, 'w', newline='', encoding=ENCODING, buffering=BUFFER) as write_obj:

    print("Starting loop")

    for row in local_file:
        # Append the batch_id text in the row / list
        write_obj.write(row.rstrip('\n').rstrip('\r') + hsep + iud_val + hsep + batch_id_val + '\n')

local_file.close()
```

My code fails with a `memoryError`.

I've tried different values for `BUFFER`, but it doesn't seem to help.

This was originally encountered on AWS fargate, running an `ubunto` based image, with 30GB of memory.  Same error reproduced on a windows laptop with 16GB of memory, running python 3.8.7.

Full stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "loop_test.py", line 27, in <module>
    write_obj.write(row.rstrip('\n').rstrip('\r') + hsep + iud_val + hsep + batch_id_val + '\n')
  File "C:\Users\k64092633\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\encodings\utf_8_sig.py", line 37, in encode
    return codecs.utf_8_encode(input, self.errors)[0]
MemoryError
```

The file has 221697553 lines, which on average are around 571 bytes long.

The error does not appear immediately, but only after processing for a while.  I think there might be some very long lines causing this.

```
with open(local_output_file, 'w', newline='', encoding=ENCODING, buffering=BUFFER) as write_obj:

    print("Starting loop")

    for row in local_file:
        row_len = len(row)
        if row_len < min_len:
            min_len = row_len
        if row_len > max_len:
            max_len = row_len
            #print("############################")
            #print(row)
        num_rows = num_rows + 1

        # Append the batch_id text in the row / list
        if row_len >1073745760:
           
            print(num_rows)
            write_obj.write(row)
```

seemed to indicate this.

Comment: How much data is in each line? (or "row" in your code). You can try `print(len(row))`

Comment: The file has 221697553 lines, which on average are around 571 bytes long

Comment: Does the MemoryError appear immediately, or after processing part of the data?

Comment: Thanks for the hints, it might be that the last line is very long.

Comment: That sounds playisble. As long as you're iterating through it like this, the number of lines shouldn't really matter, since they aren't simultaneously in memory.

Comment: Looks like a csv file is not the ideal way to manage this dataset. Have you considered moving to Postgres or Hadoop/Parquet?

Comment: What happens if you comment out the write?  I.e. is the output somehow not getting flushed or is the reads that clog things up?

Comment: If I comment out the write, it works.  The reason I'm processing this file, and adding columns, is so that I can load it into Redshift.